# Where are iTunes App store IPA files hosted once they are approved by Apple?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes, ipa, itunes-app

I understand that provisioned distributions and enterprise app can and are hosted outside of the Apple ecosystem. Just as IAPs are. But I'm wondering once you submit the IPA for approval by Apple to the public app store and it's approved. Does Apple host the IPA file? Or is hosted in a location of your choice like an IPA?

Comment: this is off topic for SO as it isn't about programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hosted on Apple's servers.